# Why is the Scala API documentation missing classes?

Tags: scala

For example, the `Predef` object says it extends `LowPriorityImplicits`, but there is no documentation for `LowPriorityImplicits`.

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html

More curious than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a part of the Scala language that is privately packaged because things otherwise can go wrong if they were to be used immaturely and compromise the soundness of the language, among other reasons. The docs for those private definitions don't get generated and published. You can see the implementation of `LowPriorityImplicits` [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8329196f299cc16946adc3f9d03a408441df6a96/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L508)